# groovy.json.JsonBuilder throws MissingMethodException in Eclipse/STS but not from groovysh

Tags: groovy

When I try to run the code below from Eclipse/STS I get the following exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
    groovy.json.JsonBuilder.message() is applicable for argument types:
    (ie.makalu.scripts.TestJsonBuilder$_run_closure1) values: 
    [ie.makalu.scripts.TestJsonBuilder$_run_closure1@d05c13]
```

but when I run it from the shell it works fine. Can anyone suggest why that may be?

I've tried this in Groovy 1.8.6 and Groovy 2.0 using STS version 2.9.2

```
package ie.makalu.scripts

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder


def json = new JsonBuilder()

json.message {
header {
    from('mrhaki')  // parenthesis are optional
    to 'Groovy Users', 'Java Users'
}
body "Check out Groovy's gr8 JSON support."
} 

println json.toString()
```

Comment: Include your class path, which Groovy libraries did you include?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using Eclipse STS - it seems to me that too many people are constantly having issues with it. Instead I would install standard Eclipse or Eclipse for Java Development (anything from a eclipse community but not a specialized STS stuff) and install Groovy (and if you need Grails) plugin on top. It works much better and you are free to install any additional plugin that might not be working under STS version.

Also I would suggest to try IntelliJ, it has nice integration with Groovy (and Grails).